# Monotonicalli Sequence Theorem

Tags: monotone-class-theorem

Using the Monotonic Sequence Theorem prove that the following sequences are convergent.
() =Σ 1/(+)
() 1=1, +1=/√(2+1) , ∈ℤ+

Comment: I don't know what you've typed, but it looks to me like a lot of squares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case (i) we have for all $n$,

$$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k} < \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1} < 1.$$

Since each term is positive the sequence of partial sums is increasing and bounded above as shown -- hence, convergent.

In case (ii) we have

$$0 < S_{n+1} = \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{S_n^2+1}}< S_n.$$

In this case, the sequence is decreasing and bounded below.